# Linux Polybar battery capacity 0 label color

Tags: configuration, window-manager

I configuring the battery module for polybar on arch linux.

I can make the battery icon red with

```
ramp-capacity-0 = 
ramp-capacity-1 = 
ramp-capacity-2 = 
ramp-capacity-3 = 
ramp-capacity-4 = 

ramp-capacity-0-foreground = #ff0000
```

This will make the icon `#ff0000`, but the `10%` label is still white. Is there any way to change the label colour so when it is using `ramp-capacity-0`, the the icon+percentage are all red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `ramp-capacity-0-foreground` will only change the color of the `ramp-capacity-0` text, as you have already noticed.

I assume you want to have the percentage in different colors depending on the battery charge, so you want to set it in the ramp. The only way you can currently do this is by setting

```
ramp-capacity-0 = %{F#ff0000}
```

However, this only works, if the percentage appears directly *after* the ramp and `ramp-capacity-0-foreground` and `label-discharging-foreground` are not set.

This works because of how polybar handles setting text color. `%{F...}` is the foreground formatting tag. If the `-foreground` property of a label or ramp (or anything else) is set, all its text will be wrapped in `%{F#...}TEXT%{F-}` where `#...` is whatever the foreground was set to and `%{F-}` is the formatting tag that resets the foreground for the following text to the bar background defined in the bar section. This is the reason that neither `ramp-capacity-0-foreground` nor `label-discharging-foreground` can be set, since if they were set, the formatting tag you added in `ramp-capacity-0` would not have any effect.

Example:

If you set `ramp-capacity-0 = %{F#ff0000}` depending on the rest of your configuration, polybar will generate the following:

- With neither `ramp-capacity-0-foreground` nor `label-discharging-foreground` set:

  `%{F#ff0000} 10%`
- With `label-discharging-foreground = #ffffff`:

  `%{F#ff0000} %{F#ffffff}10%{F-}`
- With `ramp-capacity-0-foreground = #ff0000`

  `%{F#ff0000}%{F#ff0000}%{F-} 10`

You can see, only if both are not set, can the formatting tag you have inserted manually "bleed over" into the discharging label.

References:

[Formatting Wiki Page](https://github.com/jaagr/polybar/wiki/Formatting)